# Using ILOC without chained-indexing

Tags: python, pandas

So I wanted to select the first 10 rows of a dataframe but by a specific column name (e.g 'Price'). Obviously I could do this:

df.iloc[0:10]['Price']

But I want to avoid chained indexing. Is there a way to accomplish this? I can't use LOC because there are no index that are numbered 0,1,2,etc.

Comment: Use: `df.head(10)['Price']`

Comment: What if I wanted to store the dataframe into a variable?

Comment: In that case: `df_new = df.head(10)['Price']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few other ways using `iloc` with named column:

```
df.iloc[:10, df.columns.get_loc('Price')]
```

or

```
df.iloc[:10, (df.columns=='Price').nonzero()[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer above is perfect, however it is very expensive if you are using it millions of times (using big data). For this reason you should use a dictionary to do the numeric mapping once so that you can just straight to the [X,Y] index in what essentially is a matrix:

```
columnNumber = {}
for key in df.columns:
    columnNumber[key] = df.columns.get_loc(key)
```

Then you can reuse over and over again especially when manipulating a subframe such as:

```
# Important for complicated manipulation of yearly records
yearlySubFrames = df.groupby(['Year'])
for year, yearFrame in yearlySubFrames:
    columnNumber = {}
    for key in yearFrame.columns:
         columnNumber[key] = yearFrame.columns.get_loc(key)
    ...
    ... multiple iloc operations on each subframe ...
```

Note that if you don't remove the chaining the number of warning is in the order of hundreds in log files or screen output which is very annoying.

Something very important to note however is that chaining is much faster if you reference the column first and then edit a row item. Its about 50%  to 100% more computationally efficient (that's my findings for big data). This makes it very frustrating.

Also, I've found that using *iat* is not side effect free. I've used it instead and it gives the correct answers almost everywhere but sometimes fails. Crazy stuff!